# Pausing Vimeo Videos in SwiperJS Slider on Slide Change Fails After First Video

Tags: swiper.js, vimeo

I'm using SwiperJS as a video slider and want to pause Vimeo videos when the slide is changed. This works on the first video, but subsequent videos do not pause when the slide is changed?

```
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script> 
<script>    
      var videoSwiper = new Swiper('.video-slider', {
          navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        on: {
            slideChange: function (el) {
              $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
                  var vimeoPlayer = $(this).find('iframe').get(0);                        
                  var iframe = $('#vimeo').get(0);
                  var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
                    if (vimeoPlayer) {          
                    player.pause();
                   }
                 });
                },
               },      
             });
</script>
```